# How to create a countDuplicates method recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a method that counts the number of duplicates in an array. I understand how to write it using a for loop, but I need to write it recursively.

```
public static int countDuplicates(String[] input) {
    //needs to be recursive
    int count = 0;
    if (input == null) {
        return 0;
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
        if (input[i] == input[i + 1]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count +=0;
        }
    }
    
    return count; 
}
```

The input is assumed to be in lexicographic order.

input : {"A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"}

output : 3

How do I convert this for loop to a recursion?

Comment: Would you like to share what you have tried so far and what issues you're having? And should the answer be 2? Only A and C are duplicated. Also, code doesn't returns zero for `{A, B, C, D, A, C, D, C}`

Comment: I don't think there is a "good" way to write this recursively.  Some problems are inherently linear and iterative.  So I assume this is an assignment.  For a hint, don't assume there's a "good" or elegant way to make this recursive.  You're going to have to do some ugly things to make it work that way.  The simple brute force method is probably all that's required here.

Comment: @OneCricketeer The input is assumed to be in lexicographic order and the method should count the number of elements that are duplicates not have duplicates.

Comment: Again, the "number of elements that have duplicates" is only 2 - A and C

Comment: @OneCricketeer It counts the number of elements that ARE duplicates. The second "A", second "C", and third "C" are all duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe someone have missed to call `Arrays.sort(input);` and comparison `input[i] == input[i + 1]` is not correct in case of `java.lang.String`.

correct iterative:

```java
    public static int countDuplicatesIterative(String[] input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        Arrays.sort(input);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
            if (input[i].equals(input[i + 1])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

recursive (assuming that request to turn `loop` into `recursion` actually assumes `tail recursion`):

```java
    public static int countDuplicatesRecursive(String[] input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        Arrays.sort(input);
        return doCountDuplicatesRecursive(input, 0, 0);
    }

    public static int doCountDuplicatesRecursive(String[] input, int position, int cnt) {
        if (position == input.length - 1) {
            return cnt;
        }
        if (input[position].equals(input[position + 1])) {
            cnt++;
        }
        return doCountDuplicatesRecursive(input, position + 1, cnt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question states the assumption that the input is already in the lexicographical order, the sorting is not necessary. However, the question does not provide the precise definition of the lexicographical order itself, so my assumption is that it is cease insensitive and that it does not take Unicode variants into account, so the equalsIgnoreCase() String method would be more appropriate then plain equals(). Also, the assumptions are that input is nicely defined in the sense that nulls are not allowed anywhere:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] inputs = { "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D" };

    System.out.println(countDuplicates(inputs, 0));
  }

private static int countDuplicates(String[] inputs, int start)
  {
    /*  Assumption #1 : input list is well defined
     if(inputs==null)
       return 0;
     */
    if(start<inputs.length-1)
      {
        /* Assumption #2 : elements of the list are well defined 
        if(inputs[start]==null)
          return 0;
        */
        /* Assumption #3 : Upper vs Lower Case as well as Unicode versions do not matter 
        if(inputs[start].equals(inputs[start+1]))
        */
        if(inputs[start].equalsIgnoreCase(inputs[start+1]))
          return 1+countDuplicates(inputs, start+1);
        else
          return countDuplicates(inputs, start+1);
      }
    else
      return 0;
  }
```

p.s. countDuplicates(String[], int) can be wrapped inside the countDuplicates(String[]) method if user should not be exposed/overtaxed in providing a 0 as a starting point ;-)